# How to reshape a dataset so it has only one column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataset

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
103 124 255 256 257 258 259 261 265 266
267 268 615 688 692 697 698 699 700 701
702 1548 1551 1552 1553 1561 1589 1595 1596 1597
```

I am trying to arrange it in python so that all of the numbers are in the same column like this:

```
103
124
255
256
257
```

Editing by hand is not an option since I have 20 files like this and they are around 10 pages each when opened with MS word. I tried to .stack function but it didnt give the results I wanted.

Comment: What did stack do that you didn't like?

Comment: It used the first row as some kind of index, like so                                                         0   103      267.0
     124      268.0
     255      615.0
     256      688.0
     257      692.0
             ...   
333  257    89757.0
     258    89766.0
     259    89767.0
     261    89768.0
     265    89769.0

Answer (score 0):

```
df.stack().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Looking at the results again, I saw that it skipped the first row, so I cannot do that just yet, sorry.